# Unable to use firebug performance tester with Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, firebug

I would like to measure the `performance` of the functional testing.

I was following the `tutorial` in the following link http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/.

While trying to run the test in `IDE` it is not executing and says class not found.

Could some one give a sample running code of it?

Comment: can you please elaborate...which IDE u are using and did u configure that IDE with Selenium API properly

Comment: I am using Eclipse (Kepler), currently my problem got solved by referring to the following link http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/12/selenium-performance-testing-netexport.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem got solved by referring to the following link http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/12/selenium-performance-testing-netexport.html

Initially I was using the default webdriver firefox, without user profiles. When I was unable to invoke firebug, I switched to use firefox with profiles. Since I did that, firebug is working

Comment: This is not an answer, you did not describe the problem in your question, explain the cause in the answer or give the solution.

Comment: Initially I was using the default webdriver firefox. Where I am unable to invoke the firebug, when I switched to Default firefox by using profiles firebug is working

Answer (score 0):

What is "performance of the functional testing"? Are you trying to test performance of server, so use JMeter (or smth. like that). Performance of client -- then I would look at http://yslow.org/

Comment: Thank you for additional information, I am trying to integrate Selenium functional test with Performance testing with Firebug and finally got solution.